# Is there a closed form relationship between the tuning parameter $\lambda$ and the budget parameter $s$?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Under ridge regression, we seek to find estimates of the parameters $(\beta_0, \beta_1,\ldots,\beta_p)$ of an MLR model by either:

(1) Minimizing the objective function
$$
f(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2+\lambda\sum_{i=1}^p\beta^2_i
$$

where $\hat{y_i}=\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_{i1}+\cdots+\hat{\beta}_px_{ip}$ and $\lambda \geq 0$.

(2) Minimizing

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2
$$

subject to $\sum_{i=1}^p\beta^2_i \leq s$, where $s$ is some pre-specified positive number.

I was wondering if there was a nice way we can express $s$ in terms of $\lambda$, or vice versa.

Comment: As mentioned https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191603/ridge-regression-formulation-as-constrained-versus-penalized-how-are-they-equiv the relationship depends on the observed data $(x_i, y_i)$. This is not really useful from a theory standpoint because we would like to treat the data as random, but the hyperparameter $s$ as being chosen beforehand.

Comment: @zjm Got it, thank you!